# Dice roll statistics histogram

Tags: python

This is the question I'm given:

> Analyzing dice rolls is a common example in understanding probability and statistics. Simulate rolling 2 die one hundred times. Keep track of the total of the two die. Print a histogram in which the total number of times the dice roll equals each possible value is displayed by printing a character, such as *, that number of times.

I'm having issues with not printing a `*` in each range when the dice roll doubles. I also haven't been able to figure out how to make it loop 100 times without actually printing each time.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

```py
import random
dice1 = random.randint(1,6)
dice2 = random.randint(1,6)
print(dice1, dice2)


for x in range (2, 13):

    if dice1 == 1 and dice2 == 1:
     print(x, '*', +1)
    else:
      print()
    if dice1 ==2 and dice2 == 2:
     print(x, '*', +1)
    else:
      print() 
    if dice1 == 3 and dice2 == 3:
     print(x, '*', +1)
    else:
      print() 
    if dice1 == 4 and dice2 == 4:
     print(x, '*', +1)
    else:
      print() 
    if dice1 == 5 and dice2 == 5:
     print(x, '*', +1)
    else:
      print()
    if dice1 == 6 and dice2 == 6:
      print(x, "*", +1)
    else:
      print()
```

Example output:

2s: ******

3s: ***

4s: ********

5s: *******

6s: ***********

7s: ********************

8s: *****************

9s: *********

10s: *********

11s: *******

12s: ***

Comment: What is the range of sums?  They range from 2 (1 plus 1) to 12 (6 plus 6).  How many ways can you roll 2?  (1, 1).  How many ways can you roll 3?  (1, 2) and (2, 1).  Keep going with that.  You should end up with a total number of combinations for each value from 2 to 12.  Knowing these will make you a better backgammon player.

Comment: @duffymo I'm assuming for the assignment's sake they're not tracking individual dice, so `(1,2)` and `(2,1)` are the same thing.

Comment: Correct.  This is a explanation of the probability of rolling a given sum.  The histogram produced by the code will be an approximation of this exact distribution.

Comment: It's only supposed to show when it rolls a double. a * is supposed to print showing how many times it rolled 2 2's 2 3's etc. Thank you! I may be even worse off than I thought lol

Comment: Could you show an expected outpout ? I gave it a try below as an answer.

Comment: Working with a dict, containing the possible sums should be better than hardcoding some tests. Count the number of times you get the expected sums. Then at the end draw the distribution histogram you need.

Comment: Example output:
2s: ******
3s: *** 
4s: ******** 
5s: ******* 
6s: *********** 
7s: ********************
8s: ***************** 
9s: ********* 
10s: ********* 
11s: ******* 
12s: ***
@Malo im looking at your info now thank you for your help!

Comment: I know you didn't write the quoted question, but it doesn't make sense to "Print a histogram" for these data, because the state space is discrete, not continuous. What they mean is a bar chart.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, you try to draw the distribution with '*' ?

Here you can do it

```
import random

      
results = {}
for r in range(2, 13):
    results[r]=0
    
for r in range(100):
    dice1= random.randint(1, 6)
    dice2= random.randint(1, 6)
    dices= dice1+dice2
    results[dices]+=1
    
print(results)

for r in range(2, 13):
    print("%02d"%r, "*"*results[r])
```

example output:

```
{2: 2, 3: 8, 4: 7, 5: 8, 6: 14, 7: 21, 8: 14, 9: 10, 10: 8, 11: 5, 12: 3}
02 **
03 ********
04 *******
05 ********
06 **************
07 *********************
08 **************
09 **********
10 ********
11 *****
12 ***
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!!! I made the changes I needed with your advice so it has the exact output I need now. This helped me understand so much more after iI searched each update!

Comment: If you want to have nice graphics you can use seaborn or matplotlib modules if you want.

Answer (score 1):

How about using a dictionary to store the result of 100 rolls, and then printing the final dictionary you obtained?

```
import random
  
result = {}
for k in range(2, 13):
    result.setdefault(k, 0)   #initial dict
#print(result)

for _ in range(100):
    dice1 = random.randint(1,6)
    dice2 = random.randint(1,6)
    result[dice1+dice2] += 1   #add dice throw to dict
#print(result)

for i in range(2, 13):
    print(str(i) + 's: ' + '*' * result[i])
```

Output:

```
2s: ***
3s: **********
4s: **********
5s: ************
6s: *********
7s: ***************
8s: ****************
9s: ***************
10s: ******
11s: ***
12s: *
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's some code that might help you.  I used the `matplotlib` library, which might be outside your assignment.  But perhaps the thinking will come in handy.

You'll notice that the calculated frequency distribution will come closer and closer to the theoretical distribution if you increase the number of rolls from 100 to 1,000 to 10,000.

```
import random
from collections import defaultdict
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

theoretical_counts = {
    2: 1,
    3: 2,
    4: 3,
    5: 4,
    6: 5,
    7: 6,
    8: 5,
    9: 4,
    10: 3,
    11: 2,
    12: 1
}

def die_rolls(num_rolls):
    sum_counts: defaultdict[int, int] = defaultdict(int)
    for i in range(0, num_rolls):
        x = random.randint(1, 6)
        y = random.randint(1, 6)
        sum_counts[x + y] += 1
    return sum_counts

def counts_to_frequencies(counts):
    rolls = sum(counts.values())
    frequencies = {k: v/rolls for k, v in counts.items()}
    l: list[int] = list(frequencies.items())
    l.sort()
    return dict(l)

ntrials = 100
die_rolls = die_rolls((ntrials))

plt.bar(die_rolls.keys(), die_rolls.values())
plt.title("Die Roll Counts")
plt.xlabel("Sum of Two Dies")
plt.ylabel("Sum Count")
plt.show()

die_frequencies = counts_to_frequencies(die_rolls)
plt.bar(die_frequencies.keys(), die_frequencies.values())
plt.title("Die Roll Frequencies")
plt.xlabel("Frequency of Sum of Two Dies")
plt.ylabel("Sum Frequency")
plt.show()

theoretical_frequencies = counts_to_frequencies(theoretical_counts)
plt.bar(theoretical_frequencies.keys(), theoretical_frequencies.values())
plt.title("Theoretical Die Roll Frequencies")
plt.xlabel("Frequency of Sum of Two Dies")
plt.ylabel("Theoretical Frequency")
plt.show()
```